# cicrle animation with css

Tags: css, animation

I want to create animation just like [that](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/fhxam1sb). However it doesn't look like it should. Here is fiddle of my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/063djx57/). Please help.

```
.effect-1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.effect-1::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transform: scale(0.7, 0.7);
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend altering the scale transform property on hover, instead of changing height/width in pixels (because that will affect the layout flow) whereas the transform properly creates a custom layer for your object:

```css
.effect {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1em;
}

.effect::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  border:5px solid black;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transition: .3s;
}

.effect:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn effect">M</a>
```

Also, the transition property should be added to the static state instead of hover state for optimal results.

Answer (score 1):

Hm - Not sure why you did not copy the CSS code from the [sample page](http://s.cssdeck.com/labs/full/fhxam1sb//noframe#dontkillanim). It works instantly: https://jsfiddle.net/063djx57/1/

One important thing is, `.effect-1:after {position: absolute;}`